# Typescript error: Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the error Type error: Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

```
<img onError={function(e) {
                    e.target.remove();
                }} src="../me.jpg" alt=""/>
```

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Regarding the typescript error it is correct that `.remove` doesn't exist on a EventTarget.

`addEventListener` `dispatchEvent` `removeEventListener` are the functions that do exist according to typescript

Comment: Its React ... although I realise DOM manipulation isn't a particularly Reacty way of doing things. console.log(e.target) shows that it is a HTML img element. HTML elements do have a remove method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

Replace this:

```
<img onError={event => event.target.remove()}
```

with this:

```
<img onError={event => event.currentTarget.remove()}
```

**Explanation**

The element you are dispatching the event from (`<img />`) is self-containing and cannot have any children itself. At the same time, the event handler is defined directly on the same node. This means the node that emitted the event is also the one that caught it. In other words, `event.target` will be the same as `event.currentTarget`.

These two have different type definitions. The former is defined as just `EvenTarget` while the latter is more specific `EventTarget & HTMLImageElement`. That's why `event.currentTarget` is equipped with the `remove()` method and you don't need any additional type guards.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently I have to check whether e.target is a HTML element before Typescript will let me use `.remove`, even though its pretty obvious that it will be, so doesn't seem like a great use of time to check for it.

```
if (e.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
                    e.target.remove();
                }
```